# Enable PHP extension

Tags: php, apache2, debian, lamp

I'm trying to enable a custom PHP extension (PHPShadow) but I'n having some issues.

> Extension loading not available for this sapi (apache2handler).

I'm receiving this error. How do I fix it? (My OS is Debian LAMP)

Comment: looking at what it does i would say its a waist of time makes things slower and is easy to circumvent. but that's up to you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable the `dl()` function, more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

> Warning: This function was removed from most SAPIs in PHP 5.3.0

Now, instead, *INI file* extension loading should be used, more at http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension

Part of PHP Shadow code is:

```
if(!function_exists('dl')){
    exit("Extension loading not available for this sapi (".php_sapi_name().").\n");
}
```

I guess you need to look for an updated PHP Shadow, if there is one.

Comment: I found the error, apparently the extension is compiled for a different PHP version from the one that I am running.

Comment: As I suspected, either old or otherwise wrong version :) Also, I hope you won't mind if I share this with you: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Use the installer file to guide you - it's available from the PHPshadow Download page (http://phpshadow.com/download).  It will explain where you need to copy the extension, and which php.ini file to edit and how.

Comment: You should rather add that intel to your answer. While the resource behind that link may answer the question your answer doesn't directly do that. Always try to give direct answers.